# jQuery - Selecting elements from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select first table and then second table from the html in string. I know this can be done by selector `:eq(0)` and `:eq(1)`, but

```
var firstTable = $("table", "<table></table>").length;
```

`firstTable == 0`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this to illustrate the problem:

```
var firstTable = $("table", "<div><table></table></div>").length;
// returns 1
```

The search happens *within* the context argument.

Comment: Hm, I don't usually use the `context`-style selecting, but you're definitely right about being able to pass in an HTML string - which makes sense, anyway, when you realize that `$(selector, context)` is equivalent to `$(context).find(selector)`. Time to edit my answer. +1

Comment: @Matt, I don't use it much either; I too prefer the flow of `x.find(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a second argument to `jQuery()` (aka `$()`), you are specifying a **context** to search within. That is, this:

```
$(selector, context);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$(context).find(selector);
```

So, you could rewrite your "broken" code like this to show why it's not finding a `table` element:

```
var firstTable = $("<table></table>").find("table").length;
```

...because [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) selects **descendant** elements only.

Comment: @Radek: I don't know what you mean. `.find()` works with all of the selectors that `$()` does.